# Free webstorage that is accessible via code

Tags: c#, web-storage

I have a desktop app for personal use and I would like it to be able to synchronize it's data with the net.

Since it's not trancational, I figured a solition migth be to (de)serialize the lot to a plain text format and store that in some file on the web.

Now I am looking for free storage in a way that I can access it via code, be it HTTP or FTP, that's all equal to me.  Of course I would like it to 'steady', so not some obscure free service that can be stopped at any time without prior notice  or services with bad connctions/ lots of downtime.

Also it would be nice if the data wasn't readily available for anyone who happens to google the right term, but that's optional since I can encrypt it.

I was thinking about google docs, but really anything will do as long as it is

- free
- steady (stable/trustworthy)
- accessible via code
- password protected (optional)

It would be very nice when codesnippets would come with the suggested solution! 
I'm using C#

Comment: Keep in mind that google docs has a storage limit and a set quote on the amount of documents you can create.

Comment: It's personal use and text only, I guess I'm ok with their limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Softronics is a swiss hosting company that offers [mydrive, a free 2GB WebDAV storage package](http://www.softronics.ch/en/products/mydrive.php). 
They also host [2 Gigs of FTP for €1,20 a month](http://www.softronics.ch/en/products/ftp.php)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the the [Dropbox addons](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons) provide various Ruby, Python and PHP scripts and APIs for interacting with your storage space. I would probably start with the Ruby API and write a quick C# version if I were you.

If you do, can you publish it? :)

Comment: If you do, can you publish it? :) ==> lol, I might, alreay voted you up , but I'm afraid I'm going to test the free webdav solution of Pekka first.  If I can't make that work, I will try your solution and publish it :-)

Comment: hehe, no worries.. if i get time i might do it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but pretty cheap - I use [SugarSync](http://www.sugarsync.com). Just mark the local folder and it's automatically synched to the remote server. Version history and multi-machine sync too.